Flutter - How to Disable system buttons after opening application in Kiosk mode?
I am currently developing a Launcher application using flutter. I got all installed application using dart plugin but after that if I select the application to open it opens but it do not enables the Kiosk mode. And my second concern is after opening the application in Kiosk mode I only want to disable the Home button and recent button I do not want to disable back button as I do not need to disable it according to requirement.
Code Snippet
 onTap: () async {
                          loadSelectedApp();
                          await _showConfirmationDialog(context, application);
                        },


This is where I am opening my application

Future<void> _showConfirmationDialog(
    BuildContext context, Application application) {
  return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Open Application"),
          content: Text("Are you Sure you want to open Application?"),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text("No")),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  stopKioskMode()
                      .then((value) =>
                          {DeviceApps.openApp(application.packageName)})
                      .then((value) => {showMessageAlert(context)});

                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text("Yes"))
          ],
        );
      });
}



This is the function where i am opening my application in Kiosk Mode but it do not pin my application. And I just want to disable Home button and recent button.


buddy to enable kiosk mode in your Flutter Launcher application and disable only the home and recent buttons, you need to:
Add Android native code to start kiosk mode.
Use platform channels in Flutter to call the native code.
Android Native Code
Modify MainActivity.java or MainActivity.kt:
Java:
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String CHANNEL = "com.example.kiosk_mode";

    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
            .setMethodCallHandler((call, result) -> {
                if (call.method.equals("startKioskMode")) {
                    startKioskMode();
                    result.success(null);
                }
            });
    }

    private void startKioskMode() {
        DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        ComponentName adminComponent = new ComponentName(this, MyAdminReceiver.class);

        if (dpm.isDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName())) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, adminComponent);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            dpm.setLockTaskPackages(adminComponent, new String[]{getPackageName()});
            startLockTask();
        }
    }
}

Kotlin:
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "com.example.kiosk_mode"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "startKioskMode") {
                startKioskMode()
                result.success(null)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startKioskMode() {
        val dpm = getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
        val adminComponent = ComponentName(this, MyAdminReceiver::class.java)

        if (dpm.isDeviceOwnerApp(packageName)) {
            val intent = Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN)
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, adminComponent)
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
            dpm.setLockTaskPackages(adminComponent, arrayOf(packageName))
            startLockTask()
        }
    }
}

Create MyAdminReceiver.java or MyAdminReceiver.kt:
Java:
import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver;

public class MyAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
}

Update AndroidManifest.xml:
<receiver
    android:name=".MyAdminReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.device_admin"
        android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_ADMINS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" />

Create res/xml/device_admin.xml:
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        <limit-password />
        <watch-login />
        <reset-password />
        <force-lock />
        <wipe-data />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>

Flutter Code
Add platform channel in Flutter:
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class KioskMode {
  static const platform = MethodChannel('com.example.kiosk_mode');

  static Future<void> startKioskMode() async {
    try {
      await platform.invokeMethod('startKioskMode');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed to start kiosk mode: '${e.message}'.");
    }
  }
}

Use the platform channel in your Flutter widget:
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {
    KioskMode.startKioskMode().then((value) {
      DeviceApps.openApp(application.packageName);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    });
  },
  child: Text("Yes"),
),


I added the MyAdminReceiver but it got me with lots of errors.

Are you sure you are following perfectly? The code I am using in my app is working properly. There might be some errors related to version differences. Please check the errors and feel free to ask.
